# why jquery does not work for new element created in Ajax success?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to why jquery does not work for new element created in Ajax success . one of the reason might be jquery and supporting  js file already loaded at  the  time of page load .
            how to solve this issue .
            Is there any way to load the jquery and supporting file again .

Comment: Are you trying to initialize using any plugin.

Comment: This question is too broad. Post your code so we can analyze it.

Comment: You better post sample of the code that is not working.

Comment: yes @ Sasikumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [event delegation](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for the elements created by the ajax response https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ , egarding any specific plugin initialization you will need to (re)initialize the plugin/s in the success function of your ajax call/s

Comment: This is probably the answer but what if question is regarding any specific plugin initialization?!...  And your 'only link answer' should be a comment at best

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not talking about any plugin, if you want to work with dynamically created elements, you should use `$(document).on('event', 'selector', func(){})` instead of `$('#id').on('event', func(){})`

Example :

**This wont work for dynamically generated element :**

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(triggerWords[i]) != -1) {
            alert("Alert! You've typed a blocked word.");
        }
    }
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wonpmquw/3/)

**But this would :**

```
 $(document).on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(triggerWords[i]) != -1) {
            alert("Alert! You've typed a blocked word.");
        }
    }
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wonpmquw/4/)